# mypy: How to solve this tuple confusion

Tags: python, mypy

Python 3.6 has no problems with this tuple sample:

```
# tpl is a tuple. Each entry consists of a tuple with two entries. The first
# of those is a tuple of two strings. The second one is a tuple of tuples with
# three strings.

tpl = (
    (('a', 'b'), (('1', '2', '3'), ('4', '5', '6'))),
    (('c', 'd'), (('7', '8', '9'),)),
    )

for first_tuple, second_tuple in tpl:
    str1, str2 = first_tuple
    print(str1, str2)
    for str1, str2, str3 in second_tuple:
        print('   ', str1, str2, str3)
    print()
```

output:

```
a b
    1 2 3
    4 5 6

c d
    7 8 9
```

But mypy 0.511 seems to get confused and reports errors:

```
ttpl.py:13: error: Iterable expected
ttpl.py:13: error: "object" has no attribute "__iter__"; maybe "__str__"?
```

What can i do, to help mypy understand what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mypy defaults to treating tuples as, well, tuples, rather than sequences (`Tuple[T, ...]`). When you iterate over a tuple with incompatible types, the variable’s type is determined to be `object`:

```
for x in ((1,), (2, 3)):
    reveal_type(x)
    for y in x:
        pass
```

You can provide the appropriate, very nice-looking type hint:

```
from typing import Tuple

tpl: Tuple[Tuple[Tuple[str, str], Tuple[Tuple[str, str, str], ...]], ...] = (
    (('a', 'b'), (('1', '2', '3'), ('4', '5', '6'))),
    (('c', 'd'), (('7', '8', '9'),)),
)
```

Type aliases that represent the format of your real data might help here.

Answer (score 0):

While [Ryan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773203/mypy-how-to-solve-this-tuple-confusion/44773304#44773304) gave the correct answer for python 3.6 and also gave me insight on what was going on, i would like to point out two alternative possibilities:

In case you still have to use python version without PEP 526 (Syntax for variable annotations), you could do this:

```
from typing import Tuple, Iterable

TypeOfData = Iterable[
    Tuple[
        Tuple[str, str],
        Iterable[Tuple[str, str, str]]
        ]
    ]

tpl = (
    (('a', 'b'), (('1', '2', '3'), ('4', '5', '6'))),
    (('c', 'd'), (('7', '8', '9'),)),
    ) # type: TypeOfData

for first_tuple, second_tuple in tpl:
    str1, str2 = first_tuple
    print(str1, str2)
    for str1, str2, str3 in second_tuple:
        print('   ', str1, str2, str3)
    print()][1]
```

In case you just want to keep mypy from reporting the error, this is also possible:

```
tpl = (
    (('a', 'b'), (('1', '2', '3'), ('4', '5', '6'))),
    (('c', 'd'), (('7', '8', '9'),)),
    )

for first_tuple, second_tuple in tpl:
    str1, str2 = first_tuple
    print(str1, str2)
    for str1, str2, str3 in second_tuple: # type: ignore
        print('   ', str1, str2, str3)
    print()
```

Comment: The ignoring and pre 3.6 syntax doesn't really require a separate answer, they are already there in docs and doesn't really add anything to the question.